# Symfony can't set locale to undefined

Tags: php, symfony, listener, locale

i'm trying to work with locale on a Symfony 2.7 project.
I want to set the locale to the `$request->getPreferredLanguage()` if the user is not authenticated and to set it to `$user->getLocale()` if the user is authenticated and has set his prefered locale.

I read different posts like this one: https://gist.github.com/Dattaya/1670163/450a8054d84b30c16174a75eb60f139e2602cdea
but I have a problem in the `setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser()` because i can't set the locale to `undefined`.

Here is my `config.yml` file:

```
parameters:
locale: "undefined"
session:
    storage:
        options:
            name: app_sess
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: "undefined" }
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    secret:          "%secret%"
```

I defined the services:

```
acme.locale.interactive_login_listener:
    class: acme\GeneralBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
    calls:
        - [ setSession, [@session] ]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: setLocaleForAuthenticatedUser }

acme.locale.kernel_request_listener:
    class: acme\GeneralBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser, priority: 17 }
```

Here is the method:

```
public function setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
        return;
    }

    $request = $event->getRequest();
    file_put_contents('test.txt', $request->getLocale(), FILE_APPEND);
    if ($request->getLocale() === 'undefined' ) {
        $request->setLocale($request->getPreferredLanguage());
    }
}
```

In this code `$request->getLocale()` is not `undefined`, it's `en`.
I don't understand why. Can anybody help me please ?

Comment: Is your `locale` line under `parameters` actually properly indented? As it is posted right now, it's not a child under `parameters`

Comment: Sorry this is a bad copy/paste, but this is well indented in my file

Comment: what happen if you set for exemple fr instead of "undefined" in your config.yml ? will $request->getLocale() "en" ?

Comment: I tried and "en" is written in the file, but the website is in French (French traductions are choosen)

Comment: Could it be due to the priority ? This is weird because when I set the locale to undefined, any translation was found (the website was full of translation keys), when I set it to French the website is in French. It seems that the locale variable is taken in account but not in the `$request->getLocale()`

Comment: Indeed it was the `priority`. I set it to `10` and the locale was as defined in the `config.yml` file (`undefined` in my case). Now, the problem is that the second method (`setLocaleForAuthenticatedUser()`) is called but the result is ignored:
If i'm not logged in, the `$request->getLocale()` is undefined so the locale is set to getPreferedLanguage (`fr` for me). When i'm logging in, the second method is called and set the locale to `$user->getLanguage()` (`en`) but then the first method is called and the result of `$request->getLocale()` is `undefined`, not `en`

Comment: can you give us the defined route?

Comment: This is not for a specific route, this is for every routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution:
`config.yml` file

```
parameters:
    locale: "undefined"

framework:
    translator:      { fallback: "en" }
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
```

`services.yml` file

```
acme.locale.interactive_login_listener:
    class: acme\GeneralBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
    calls:
        - [ setSession, [@session] ]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: setLocaleForAuthenticatedUser }

acme.locale.kernel_request_listener:
    class: acme\GeneralBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser, priority: 10 }
```

`LocaleListener` file

```
class LocaleListener {

public function setSession(Session $session)
{
    $this->session = $session;
}


public function setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
        return;
    }

    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $sessionLocale = $request->getSession()->get('_locale');
    if ($sessionLocale == '') {
        $request->setLocale(substr($request->getPreferredLanguage(), 0, 2));
    } else {
        $request->setLocale(substr($sessionLocale, 0, 2));
    }
}


public
function setLocaleForAuthenticatedUser(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
    $preferences = $user->getPreferences();

    if ($preferences !== null && gettype($preferences) === 'array' && isset($preferences['language'])) {
        $event->getRequest()->setLocale(substr($preferences['language'], 0, 2));
        $this->session->set('_locale', substr($preferences['language'], 0, 2));
    }
}
```

}

The aim of this solution is to check if `$request->getSession()->get('_locale');` is empty. This is the case when user is still not logged in. When the users log in, the `setLocaleForAuthenticatedUser` method is called and we set the session locale to the user preferred locale.
Note that substring are used to prevent problems with accurate locales such as fr_FR
It could be better, but this is a working solution